# Install phpmyadmin without selection apache2 or lighttpd

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04, php

I use command Ubuntu: *sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin*

In process installing I inform about selection type of server: *apache2 and lighttpd.*
My server is build only on *Nginx + php_fpm*.
How i can install phpmyadmin without selection apache2 or lighttpd?
Sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install `php5-fpm` and then install `phpmyadmin`.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

The software, phpMyAdmin, requires a Web server and PHP. If PHP and a Web server have not yet been installed, then the default action is to use Apache. The package, `php5-fpm`, satisfies the requirements; thus, installing `phpmyadmin` after `php5-fpm` results in only the following additional package dependencies.

```
dbconfig-common javascript-common libjs-codemirror libjs-jquery
libjs-jquery-cookie libjs-jquery-event-drag libjs-jquery-metadata
libjs-jquery-mousewheel libjs-jquery-tablesorter libjs-jquery-ui
libjs-underscore libmcrypt4 php-gettext php5 php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
```

Although PHP-FPM is not a Web server, the package maintainer understood that if `php5-fpm` has been installed, then the Ubuntu server will utilize some other Web server that uses the FastCGI Process Manager (FPM), and there is no need to know which Web server.

Answer (score 0):

considering you have a lemp stack

you could also skip the queston with tab to "ok". 
this might force phpmyadmin to install apache2, at least on the newest built, it wasnt like that before.

than when an error arrives that apache2 could not start, this is due nginx php-fpm already using the port, just toggle apache to start with this shell command

```
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```